# HTML marquee issue

Tags: html, css, marquee

Yes, I know marquee HTML code is outdated, but I have very little knowledge of code and CSS is beyond my capabilities at the moment!

I have a marquee banner on my website, to display company logos for brands we have worked with. However, I have two issues:

1. The marquee has an unwanted scroll function on it despite no scroll code included, and when scrolled, you can see a very small snippet of code?
2. The blank space before the first image and after the last looks awful, can this be removed?

The code is below. Yes, the image files have been duplicated in the code to try to avoid website visitors seeing a large empty blank space.

```css
.Marquee-box {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1310px;
    height: 80px;
}
.MyMarquee {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 110%;
    height: 110%;
    font-size: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
.MyMarquee div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.MyMarquee a,
.MyMarquee img {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: hidden;
    color: #ffffff;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="Marquee-box">
    <marquee class="MyMarquee" id="my_marquee" direction="left" behavior="7" scrollamount="7" onmouseover="" onmouseout="">
        <div><img src="" width="130" height="70" alt="marquee image" /></div>
        <div><img src="" width="120" height="50" alt="marquee image" /></div>
        <div><img src="" width="130" height="70" alt="marquee image" /></div>
        <div><img src="" width="120" height="80" alt="marquee image" /></div>
        <div><img src="" width="150" height="60" alt="marquee image" /></div>
        <div><img src="" width="130" height="90" alt="marquee image" /></div>
        <div><img src="" width="150" height="50" alt="marquee image" /></div>
    </marquee>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unwanted scroll was coming because of width attribute...I have commented out the same...

And I didn't get the second problem that you have mentioned and I didn't find any blank spaces...Can you attach any screenshot to elaborate the problem?

```css
.Marquee-box {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
   // width: 1310px;//scrollbar is coming because of this
    height: 80px;
}
.MyMarquee {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 110%;
    height: 110%;
    font-size: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
.MyMarquee div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.MyMarquee a,
.MyMarquee img {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: hidden;
    color: #ffffff;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="Marquee-box">
    <marquee class="MyMarquee" id="my_marquee" direction="left" behavior="7"  scrollamount="7" onmouseover="" onmouseout="">
        <div><img src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp1984893.jpg" width="130" height="70" alt="marquee image" /></div>
        <div><img src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp1984893.jpg" width="120" height="50" alt="marquee image" /></div>
        <div><img src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp1984893.jpg" width="130" height="70" alt="marquee image" /></div>
        <div><img src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp1984893.jpg" width="120" height="80" alt="marquee image" /></div>
        <div><img src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp1984893.jpg" width="150" height="60" alt="marquee image" /></div>
        <div><img src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp1984893.jpg" width="130" height="90" alt="marquee image" /></div>
        <div><img src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp1984893.jpg" width="150" height="50" alt="marquee image" /></div>
    </marquee>
</div>
```

Comment: What width in px should I change it to? Sorry for such infantile questions, I am very new to this!

The second issue I should have worded better. Rewritten;

Does the marquee function allow the images to scroll right to left, but have the images start already on screen, up towards/to meet the left hand side of the marquee container?

I really hope that makes sense and thank you very much for such a quick reply! Really do appreciate it! :)